# isset and $_GET with url, fix mod_rewrite

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I have done mod_rewrite for category.php.

```
RewriteRule ^category/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)(&type=[A-Za-z0-9-]+)?(&r=[A-Za-z0-9-]+)?(&g=[A-Za-z0-9-]+)?(&v=[A-Za-z0-9-]+)?(&page=[A-Za-z0-9-]+)?/?$ /category.php?c=$1&type=$2&r=$3&g=$4&v=$5&page=$6 [L]
```

With this url in the browser;

```
http://localhost/category/general
```

I test if `v` exists

```
if(isset($_GET['v'])) {
echo "yes";
}
```

`yes` is displayed but it isn't in the url?  If the url was this..

```
http://localhost/category/general&v=1
```

then `yes` should be displayed.  How do i fix this?

Comment: i think a better test would be empty($_GET['v'])

Comment: `v=` **is** in the URL. That's what `mod_rewrite` does. It supplies server with a changed URL.

Comment: Try explaining what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: v is set specifically in the rewrite... it just happens to be to an empty string.

Comment: i thought `isset($_GET['v'])` checks if `v=` is visible in the url?

Comment: `v=` means `$_GET["v"] = ""`, while `v=something` means `$_GET["v"] = "something"`. So, if you just want a difference between the two, @Orangepill is right: use `!empty()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are always calling `category.php` with `c=$1&type=$2&r=$3&g=$4&v=$5&page=$6` as the query string. Using `isset()` is inefficient as it will always be set. I would use `empty()` instead.

```
if(!empty($_GET['v'])) {
    echo "yes";
}
```

Comment: `isset() && !empty()` together makes no sense as `empty()` checks if variable is set.